# one to many images grails

Tags: jquery, image, grails, one-to-many

Im trying to upload several (one to many) images using grails and jquery. I've been following this [post](http://www.2paths.com/2009/10/01/one-to-many-relationships-in-grails-forms/), but I couldn't make it so far. The thing is that it seems that everything is ok, but when you try to save images (creating a building for instance) it doesn't save any image.

I think, the key of the problem is in the gsp params for the file types(images). These are the params that arrive to my controller:
[name:1, type:1, create:Crear,
imagesList[0].data:org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@d9278f,
imagesList[0]:data:org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@d9278f], action:save, controller:building]

So, I think that these params are wrong for what I wanna do. Any ideas, or sample code to fix this?? Thanks!

My save() method in the building controller

```
def save() {
    def buildingInstance = new Building(params)
    if (!buildingInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [buildingInstance: buildingInstance])
        return
    }                    
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'building.label', default: 'Building'), buildingInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: buildingInstance.id)
}
```

My domains:

```
 class Building {

    def Integer type
    def String name

    List images = new ArrayList()    
    static hasMany = [images: Image]

    static constraints = {
        name()
        type() 
    }   

    static mapping = {
        images cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }

def getImagesList() {
    return LazyList.decorate(images,FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Image.class))
}
```

}

```
 class Image {
    def byte[] data 
    static belongsTo = [building: Building]

    boolean deleted 
    static transients = [ 'deleted' ]

    static constraints = { data(maxSize:10000000,required:true,blank:false)  }
 }
```

My JSP's:

_Images.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addChild() {
var childCount = ${buildingInstance?.images.size()} + 0;
var htmlId = "image" + childCount;
var deleteIcon = "${resource(dir:'images/skin', file:'icon_delete.png')}";
var templateHtml = "<div id='" + htmlId + "' name='" + htmlId + "'>\n";
templateHtml += "<input type='file' id='imagesList[" + childCount + "].data' name='imagesList[" + childCount + "].data' />\n";
templateHtml += "<span onClick='$(\"#" + htmlId + "\").remove();'><img src='" + deleteIcon + "' /></span>\n";
templateHtml += "</div>\n"; 
$("#childList").append(templateHtml);
 childCount++; 
}
</script>

<div id="childList">
    <g:each var="image" in="${buildingInstance.images}" status="i">
        <!-- Render the image template (_image.gsp) here -->
        <g:render template='image'
            model="['image':image,'i':i,'hidden':false]" />
    </g:each>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add image" onclick="addChild();" />
```

_image.gsp

```
<div id="image${i}" class="image-div" <g:if test="${hidden}">style="display:none;"</g:if>>
    <g:hiddenField name='imagesList[${i}].id' value='${image?.id}'/>
    <g:hiddenField name='imagesList[${i}].deleted' value='false'/>

    <input type="file" name="imagesList[${i}].data"  value="${image?.data}" />

    <span class="del-image">
        <img src="${resource(dir:'images/skin', file:'icon_delete.png')}" 
            style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already found where it was the mistake. Just changed the "imagesList" values in the gsp for "images" as the name in the domain and it works. The post I was following seems to be wrong.